# Distribution of Reputation on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer

It's commonly said that 10% of the worldwide population have 90% of the wealth (also known as the [Pareto Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle)). Just for fun I wanted to check the distribution of wealth (reputation-wise) of users on Stack Overflow to see if there is a correlation.

I used the Data Explorer to query this:

### [Data Explorer Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228230/do-10-of-users-hold-90-of-the-reputation-on-stack-overflow)

The query I wrote returned:

```
TotalRep  | UserCount | Top10RepTotal | Bottom90RepTotal | Top10%  | Bottom90%
==============================================================================
453105542 | 3536573   | 429270432     | 23835190         | 94.7396 | 5.2604
```

So according to this, the top 10% of users currently hold nearly 95% of the total rep on the site.

Is this query accurate? Are there users that should be excluded, i.e. anonymous users? How would I filter them?

Also, is the reputation of the top users, i.e. Jon Skeet accurate, as I'm sure I've read before he's on a triple roll-over or something because he had too much wealth?

**Update**

So based on comments and the answer from @eis, here's the query excluding users with no activity on the site, i.e. users with 1 reputation point:

### [Data Explorer Query (More Than 1 Reputation)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230915/)

Query results:

```
TotalRep  | UserCount | Top10RepTotal | Bottom90RepTotal | Top10% | Bottom90%
==============================================================================
450999136 | 1430167   | 392932581     | 58066946         | 87.124 | 12.8752
```

Looking at only these users, the user count is reduced by almost 60%. The results now show that the top 10% of users hold around 87% of the total reputation on the site, a reduction of around 8% from the previous query.

@KarolyHorvath:

> I wouldn't consider anybody with less than.. say a 100 rep a serious
> user. That long tail below that threshold massively distorts the
> percenteges.

### [Data Explorer Query (More Than 100 Reputation)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230965)

Query results:

```
TotalRep  | UserCount | Top10RepTotal | Bottom90RepTotal | Top10%  | Bottom90%
==============================================================================
425661417 | 313223    | 292350992     | 133312738        | 68.6816 | 31.319
```

Comment: It's called the [Pareto Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle).  It's widely applicable to many areas of life.

Comment: REDISTRIBUTE REP!  For TOO LONG Jon Skeet has been HOARDING REP, preventing the 99% from gaining rep themselves!

Comment: There are 90047 pages of users in the [Users tab/All](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).  The first user having more than 1 reputation starts on [page 34530](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=34530&tab=reputation&filter=all).  So only about 38 percent of all user accounts have a reputation greater than 1.

Comment: You might also be interested in poking at the [reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow).

Comment: @Tanner take away ALL users who don't have 1, that will change. a BUNCH of people only create an account to ask a question and never do anything more.

Comment: @Will LET'S TAKE HIM DOWN... although I don't think we can :(

Comment: I'll go back to the drawing board and edit the query to see what it produces.

Comment: No, no, no! Not the Occupy StackOverflow Movement! We'll have to call in the Spanish Inquisition!

Comment: I believe a similar pattern exists on the ASP.net web site as well. very skewed totals. And I think MS throws new employees in there to maintain the site, so there are fewer extremely high ranking reps.

Comment: Changing it to account only people with more than 2 rep only change it by about 7%, 86.6888% and 12.8456%

Comment: I know this has been pretty light-hearted, but I couldn't resist blogging: http://www.rubycuts.com/2014/10/all-i-need-to-know-about-business-i-learned-on-stackoverflow/

Comment: Hang on, are we advocating a communist redistribution of rep here? I'm no Marxist! :)

Comment: The top 1% are taking everything from us! Oh wait, I'm in the top 1%...

Comment: Rep has to be redistributed because users with more then 100k rep can delete all posts of a user and ban him for 2 years by just coughing.

Comment: The Pareto principle is a consequence of power law distribution.  Power law distributions are so common that whenever you see a different distribution, it demands an explanation.

Comment: @DavidG: I don't like the look of that, [equally dividing rep would be such a downer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230946/how-much-reputation-would-we-get-in-commie-so).

Comment: I wouldn't consider anybody with less than.. say a 100 rep a serious user. That long tail below that threshold massively distorts the percenteges. top10%: 68.7% http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230965/do-10-of-users-hold-90-of-the-reputation-on-stack-overflow-where-rep-100

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I suppose everyone is entitled to some wealth though, I mean rep. Will update to include these results.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think 200 is a better threshold. You get 101 rep by merely having earned a bit of reputation on some other site of the network. Most of my accounts have only 101 reputation. Or perhaps we should use the number of posts as threshold instead of some reputation value.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's true, although I would hazard a guess that a high percentage of users that access the network would do so via SO as a starting point rather than the other way round.

Comment: also: the top 20% have more than 98% of all the rep...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Answer to the question:**

Excluding those users with no contributions (1 rep) would certainly help increase the usefulness of your query. As far as I know, Jon Skeet's rep is accurate, but he would have a *lot* more if it wasn't for the daily rep limit.

**Response about results:**

To the results, and to respond to the post by @Adam893; high rep users have high rep *because* they are more active on the site, not because it is "easier" for them to earn it. Its true that you occasionally get "income" from older posts, and I don't have enough posts to say what this effect is definitively (perhaps another query is in order?) but it is a *very* minor source of reputation for me.

It is not any "easier" for high-rep members to earn more rep, other than a potential bias towards liking their post more due to that rep. In reality though, high-rep users tend to have higher quality answers (and more of them) and so their posts get more votes, and they get more rep.

Jon Skeet posts a *ton* of *great* answers every day, which is why he hits the rep cap (almost) every day (and has a million "Nice Answer" badges). New users tend to not answer as much, and worse, post poor questions that get downvoted, so they tend to accumulate rep more slowly. To say that the high rep users are "keeping the other users down" is crazy. I've gained 16K in 7 months, and no one tried to "keep me down".

The system seems to be working as designed (with notable exceptions like FGITW) and given the levels of participation/quality, I am not surprised by the query results.

Comment: I recently came across a user who hits the rep capo almost every day despite not visiting the site for the last two years. It's all from older posts.

Comment: Not saying this is the norm, but they were no Jon Skeet and living large.

Comment: @JohnConde I wish I had that kind of income. Still, its hard for me to say they should be penalized just because people today think their answer from two years ago is of high quality (not saying you think that, it was mentioned by the other poster).

Comment: I agree. There's no perfect system but I think what we have now is ok. There's plenty of rep to be had by those who make an effort and give good answers (and ask good questions).

Comment: It's easier for people with a bunch of old posts to gain rep in the same way that it's easier for people with assets to generate income. (I'm perfectly fine with it.)

Comment: Questions with more upvotes appear on top of results and so are more upvoted. The system tends to give rep in an exponential fashion, and therefore intensify the disparity in distribution.

Comment: One could argue that exactly 101 reputation (for users trusted on the SE network) should also be excluded.

Answer (score 60):

[The Top 1% of Users have 54.1% of the Reputation.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230568/we-are-the-99)

## #WeAreThe99%

Comment: A much more interesting query would be where the current cutoff to be in the top 1% is. I want to know if I'm rich :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's currently [4864](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230585/who-are-the-1). You're very rich.

Comment: Yay! Somehow, I expected that it would be higher... +1 for your awesome query work!

Comment: Woo hoo... I'm in the top 1%... Now what to do with my new found richness!

Comment: You can also find out [exactly what percentile of users you are in](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230605/what-percentile-of-users-am-i-in-reputation-wise)

Comment: There are 47 percent of the people who will vote for @JonSkeet no matter what.  All right, there are 47 percent who are with him, who are dependent upon stackoverflow, who believe that they are programmers, who believe that stackoverflow has a responsibility to care for them, who believe that they are entitled to answers, to points, to badges, to you name it.  Then that's an entitlement.

Comment: Sorry, @BradleyDotNET; I was just trying to be funny.  Figured it was OK on meta.  Borrowing from http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2012/09/full-transcript-mitt-romney-secret-video#47percent prompted by the 99% tag in the answer.

Comment: @CarlManaster No problem with humor on Meta, just didn't understand the joke :) The link provides a lot of context, so thanks for providing it!

Comment: Where's the poverty line?

Comment: @SantaClaus where the cost of food & housing is more than 20% higher the median cost for a member of stack overflow? ... you can't spend magical unicorn points on food & housing.

Comment: It feels so wrong upvoting this past 54

Comment: Rather than editing the number in place, maybe keep a history in the answer itself so you can see the percentage climbing. Bunch of hoarders.

Answer (score 10):

For the interested:

Now that I run it with users > 1 rep, the numbers seem to be

```
Total Rep  | UserCount | Top 10 Rep Total | Bottom 90 Rep Total | Top 10 % | Bottom 90 %
========================================================================================
450999136  | 1430167   | 392932581        | 58066946            | 87.1249  | 12.8752
```

Which is quite different than what it is for all users:

```
Total Rep  | UserCount | Top 10 Rep Total | Bottom 90 Rep Total | Top 10 % | Bottom 90 %
======================================================================================== 
453105542  | 3536573   | 429270432        | 23835190            | 94.7396  | 5.2604
```