# How many new users with only 1 point are currently on SO?

Tags: discussion

Every time I open a question on SO, the OP is 90% a newbie with 1 point. Is there a way I can "search" SO with a query to find how many people are with one point on SO?

Comment: Yes, you want the data explorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=number+of+users+with+1+rep

Comment: 3,192,479. Courtesy of [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369861/number-of-users-with-1-rep) (second result).

Comment: These are *accounts*.  How many people (breathing human beings) are behind them and how many were banned before is completely unknown.  Not 3 million.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that many of these 'users' have strings, or hands in them.

Comment: I would rather say *feet*.

Comment: Low reputation isn't necessarily an indication of bad question content.

Comment: Related: [What is the median reputation level on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296967/2564301) and [What is the distribution of reputation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272749/2564301)

Comment: aprox. 4.5mio to date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to take a look at [the SE data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

[A basic query, listing number of accounts by reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/433099):

```sql
select reputation, count(*)
from users
where reputation <= 100
group by reputation
order by reputation
```

As Hans said, there's simply no saying how many users there are per account.